# How should I deal with Fedora's short life cycle?

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade

I have been using Fedora as my primary distribution since very long. One thing that *"bothers"* me is its relatively short life cycle. I install its latest release, restore my backup, customize the applications, take a sigh of relief but by then the new release is just around the corner.

> Fedora has a comparatively short life
>   cycle: version X is maintained until
>   one month after version X+2 is
>   released. With 6 months between
>   releases, the maintenance period is a
>   very short 13 months for each version. [Wikipedia](http://bit.ly/ONoUh)

Once I used pre-upgrade when moving from Fedora 9 to 10. It didn't work smoothly. The new upgraded Fedora was using the old kernel images of Fedora 9. Took me long to figure it out and I had to use live usb to fix it. Since then I decided not to use `pre-upgrade` or `Upgrade an existing installation` option. I had some hiccups with applications too.

Using `fresh install` seems safer. But now I have to backup all data, along with my scripts and rc files and restore it again. This takes time along with installing apps that are not installed by default and removing not-required apps.

Main problem is customization settings of each application. From Firefox only, I would have to export saved passwords, bookmarks, saved sessions, preferences of different extensions, etc. Some other applications do not provide option of save/export settings at all. So I have to configure each one manually.

All in all, upgrading to latest release takes time, even longer if my net connection goes down for some reason. Each time I upgrade, I cannot take it out my mind that within few months a new release will be knocking my door, and I will have to repeat the whole exercise again.

1. What could be a painless and easy procedure to take backups of all data and to restore it? I would prefer a command line solution.
2. How can I preserve settings of applications, if they do not provide an option to export settings?
3. If you are Fedora user, what do you do to keep up with its frequent releases?
4. How can I make this whole procedure faster and less painful? Its the amount of time and efforts that an upgrade takes altogether which made me post this question. How can I make my life easier?

Comment: Just to mention the obvious, if you don't want all the latest new features, switch to a distro that upgrades less often. CentOS, Ubuntu LTS, Debiaan stable, etc.

Comment: https://github.com/xsuchy/fedora-upgrade (also available as rpm in official distro) works great for upgrading fedora to newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I use an external drive, where I backup some of my folders and dotfiles with `rsync -avz` once the first snapshot is taken, it only needs very little data to move onto the external drive for backups.
2. Pretty much all of that information is stored in a dotfile or in some dotdirectory. All you need to do, is backup those directories. That's what I do anyway, and it's been working for years. Keep in mind however, that sometimes a newer version won't play nice with the older config files, so it's not guaranteed to work every single time.
3. It all depends on what big of a change the next release is. For instance, when the file systems don't change, I don't see a reason to re-install anymore. It was all different back when FC6 was around. Upgrading was a pain, and I usually made fresh installs back then.
   From Fedora 8 onward, `preupgrade` was working fine, I didn't have had any issues with it. I did however a fresh install for Fedora 13, since I wanted all my hard drives to be formatted in `ext4`. Other than that, upgrading to latest version of Fedora usually works well. As of this edit, I've recently upgraded to Fedora 24. By now, the upgrade process with `dnf` goes smothly, although I think there is room for improvement. Generally, problems only arise when the upgrade process is aborted mid-install, or mid-cleanup.
4. Usually, keep somewhat track, of what changes you do to the system. What files in `/etc/` you changed, what programs you compiled yourself, or what libs you put into `/usr/lib/` yourself, etc. This makes life much easier, as well as a backup, that is constantly kept up to date. Preupgrade works fine by now, but when you want to change The file system or so, there's no way around reinstalling. The [upgrade guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PreUpgrade) of Fedora will advice you when you should indeed reinstall instead of doing an upgrade. The PreUpgrade manual says, it's possible to upgrade from F11 directly to F13, for example. I would advice against it. Since older Fedoras aren't upgraded, the PreUpgrade package is most likely outdated. With the latest versions and the newer upgrade processes with `dnf` and the [`system-upgrade`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) plugin, this isn't as much of an issue, really. Conflicting file versions are stored with the extension `.rpmsave`, and you can then later resolve these issues with `rpmconf -a`.

This won't help, but when you're a OpenBSD user, you need to make most changes manually and you can't upgrade to the latest release from any other than the previous one.

**A word of warning:** What might somewhat ruin your day, are 3rd party repositories that aren't "ready" for the new release yet. This happens almost routinely with dropbox, and even with RPMfusion. It takes RPMfusion about two weeks to get in sync with the new release, but sometimes four moths for Dropbox to fix their repos. So, when you're using something like RPMfusion, etc. I advice checking if they're ready. Otherwise waiting another week or two won't really hurt, and it'll save you a lot of headaches. Especially when dealing with nVidia drivers and such.

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same problem with my Fedora installation, and the solution is quite simple : partitions. Since I have created a /home partition, I format / but all my preferences for every program are staying. Just separate your data from your system with partition, and on reinstall, make sure to format only /, and specify your home partition as mounted on /home.
Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

While once in a while Fedora updates give grief, the process usually runs smoothly (specially if you update over the 'net and wait a month or so for the toothing problems to get ironed out). Just upgraded my netbook from Fedora 16 to Fedora 17 the `yum` way (had separate `/` and `/usr`, even that hair-raising dance went smoothly), and then using `FedUp` to Fedora 18. Some unofficial `texlive` packages gave some problems, but nothing too serious. Using that one right now. Had backed up my complete account and all of `/etc` and a complete list of the installed packages to a big pendrive, just to be on the safe side.

Sure, some configuration changes; and the installation process just can't track down and fix configuration local to your account.

Answer (score 1):

RedHat has a tool called kickstart[1] to automate installs.  Not sure if Fedora offers the same tool or not, but it might help getting the initial install underway.

I also second the separate /home partition.  Backups are still necessary in case of a slip of the finger, but it makes life way easy.

1. http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/KickStart-HOWTO.html

Comment: Yes, Fedora has Kickstart.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded Fedora 16 to 17, then to 19, then to 21, and I think most of the issues I hit probably would have been hit in a clean install anyway.  However, each upgrade took about a full day including doing a full drive image beforehand, then following all the detailed upgrade procedures I've read which include doing things like checking for RPM packages which are no longer maintained in the YUM repositories and finding replacements, verifying all packages, searching for any configuration files which have had .rpmnew files created and merging in the changes, etc.

I think a less time-consuming solution is to use CentOS instead, and then run Fedora in a chroot environment (perhaps a container is a more modern way of doing this) for the applications that CentOS doesn't provide.  I use `schroot` to manage the chroot and it will mount my home directory in the same place in the chroot environment so things are fairly seamless.  It can be a little tricky to get video acceleration and sound working in the chroot, perhaps containers deal with that better.

I currently have Fedora 22 in a chroot, and that will no longer be supported in a few weeks, so I'll create a new chroot with a newer version of Fedora but be able to jump back to the old version if some application is misbehaving in the new version, which is a lot more likely to happen in Fedora than in CentOS.